# Horizontally space items NSLayoutConstraints like space-between

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, spacing

I've gotten my three horizontal items to be spaced evenly from one another (similar to space-around in CSS).

|--X--X--X--|

However, I want them to be spaced similar to how space-between would do so in CSS, with a bit of spacing from each edge:
|-X----X----X-|

Is there any way to do that? The code I have for the horizontal spacing is below. I'm new to NSLayoutConstraints. Thanks!

```
addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0(v2)][v1(v2)][v2]|", views: commentButton, likeButton, mapButton)
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no "built-in" way to center a view using Visual Format Language. You can find attempts that may seem to work, but may not be reliable and may fail if iOS changes things.

You *can* get the layout you want using a couple of "spacer" views:

```
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|-8-[btn1(btn3)][spacer1(spacer2)][btn2(btn3)][spacer2][btn3]-8-|",
        options: [.alignAllCenterY],
        metrics: nil,
        views: views))
```

Note: much easier to keep track of things by using an actual views dictionary, rather than a "helper" that gives you v1, v2, v3, etc...

Result:

[image]

So, `|-8-` and `-8-|` means `8-pts from the edge`, so you have a little padding on left and right.

`btn1` and `btn2` are set Equal Width to `btn3`, so all 3 buttons keep matching widths.

`spacer1` is set Equal Width to `spacer2`, so both spacers keep matching widths.

The spacer views backgrounds are set to `.clear` ... but, since we haven't given them a height constraint, they will have a height of Zero and won't be visible anyway.

Here is the code I used - you can run it directly in a Playground Page, or by using it as a view controller:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    var commentButton: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.setTitle("Comment", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = .red
        return b
    }()

    var likeButton: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.setTitle("Like", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = .red
        return b
    }()

    var mapButton: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.setTitle("Map", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = .red
        return b
    }()

    var spacer1: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return v
    }()

    var spacer2: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(commentButton)
        view.addSubview(likeButton)
        view.addSubview(mapButton)

        view.addSubview(spacer1)
        view.addSubview(spacer2)

        let views = [
            "btn1" : commentButton,
            "btn2" : likeButton,
            "btn3" : mapButton,
            "spacer1" : spacer1,
            "spacer2" : spacer2,
        ]

        views.forEach {
            $0.value.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "V:|-8-[btn1]",
            options: [],
            metrics: nil,
            views: views))

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "H:|-8-[btn1(btn3)][spacer1(spacer2)][btn2(btn3)][spacer2][btn3]-8-|",
            options: [.alignAllCenterY],
            metrics: nil,
            views: views))

    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

---

**Edit:**

By the way, it is considerably simpler to use `NSLayoutConstraint` rather than `VFL` -- more flexible too. And, it doesn't need the "spacer" views.

Here is an example. It produces the exact same layout as above (again, can be run in a Playground Page or as a view controller source):

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    var commentButton: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.setTitle("Comment", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = .red
        return b
    }()

    var likeButton: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.setTitle("Like", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = .red
        return b
    }()

    var mapButton: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.setTitle("Map", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = .red
        return b
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(commentButton)
        view.addSubview(likeButton)
        view.addSubview(mapButton)

        [commentButton, likeButton, mapButton].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // commentButton 8-pts from top, 8-pts from left
            commentButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            commentButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),

            // likeButton 8-pts from top, centered horizontally
            likeButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            likeButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // mapButton 8-pts from top, 8-pts from right
            mapButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            mapButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            // commentButton and likeButton widths equal to mapButton width
            commentButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapButton.widthAnchor),
            likeButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapButton.widthAnchor),

            ])

    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```